# Rounded corners with Canvas/VML in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, canvas, rounded-corners, vml

I'm using the [JRC](http://jrc.rctonline.nl/) (jQuery Rounded Corners) plugin for rounded corners. It works in almost all browsers (including the crappy IE6) except IE8. Is there any workaround for the newest sh** from MS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to see if you are using the latest version of excanvas:
http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/downloads/list

Unfortunately if that doesn't work you can ask on the google group if there is any suggestions.

IE8 is supposedly fixed according to this:
http://explorercanvas.blogspot.com/2009/03/new-explorer-canvas-release.html

Answer (score 0):

Well even the homepage of JRC states

> The current version does not work with ie8

So I guess not.

---

But you could use the [DD_roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) library only for IE8 (maybe include via conditional comments only for IE8)